# Migrate default data from UserDefaults.standard to UserDefaults(suitName:)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, userdefaults

I am making an app with a widget which shares an accent color through UserDefaults.

Now through out the app I have used `UserDefaults.standard`, but after adding widgets it was necessary to create app groups, so I created app groups to share persistence data with the widget.

I am not able to share my defaults with the widget with obvious reason that `UserDefaults.standard` don't share data on app extensions (ie: Widget etc) for that we need to use UserDefaults(suitName:  "appGroup").

Now we know that we migrate sqlite database for persistence to the app group url path from the old store.

Can we do it similarly for the UserDefaults.standard to UserDefaults(suitName:)?
Because if I use UserDefaults(suitName) directly all the defaults are reset.

Please correct me if I am wrong or suggest a good practice.

Comment: You are storing a database in UserDefaults? UserDefaults is designed for small data like settings. It is the most insecure unstable type of storage.

Comment: No, no. I am using UserDefaults for storing an accent color, just gave an example of CoreData migration for app groups, so thought is there a similar way for UserDefaults or what.

Comment: If there is one settings that is absolutely needed, you could check if that value is present with UserDefault.suiteName, if not, show an error message asking to launch the main app. In the main app, at launch, check that needed value, if not there, transfer all UserDefault(suiteName: "...").setValue(forKey: "someKey", UserDefaults.standard(...), etc. ?

Comment: Kind of loop the dicitonaryRepresentation of defaults.standard and add to the suit name? @Larme

Comment: Yes, except that there are other potential values in the whole UserDefaults.standard, that "aren't yours". That's why I'd do it manually, or list all your keys and filter the `dictionaryRepresentation` content according to the keys.

Comment: This gives an error message in the console, also the defaults are not reflected in the first run, but second one.

Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x2814d8ab0> (Domain: group.com.companyname.appname, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd @Larme